# Declaring OpenCV 3.0 GpuMat Mask and Filling With Value

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.0 with VS2012 C++/CLI on a Win 8.1 64 bit machine.

In addition, I have an NVidia GTX 760 with CUDA 7.0.

I am trying to detect SURF keypoints but only within an ROI. I got this working in non-GPU code and am now trying to do the same thing using the GPU implementation. In order to do that, I understand that I first need to create a mask filled with a background value (0) and then specify an ROI within the mask and fill that with another value (255). I then pass this mask in as part of the SURF call.

The following code is supposed to create the mask and fill it with zeros.

```
cuda::GpuMat tMask(dImages->d_gpuGrayFrame->size(), dImages->d_gpuGrayFrame->type());
tMask.setTo(Scalar::all(0));  // crashes on this line
```

I have also tried:

```
cuda::GpuMat tMask(dImages->d_gpuGrayFrame->size(),CV_8U);
tMask.setTo(Scalar::all(0));  // crashes on this line
```

I have also tried both of the above but with the setTo line as:

```
tMask.setTo(0);  // crashes on this line
```

But that still crashes.  It is a bit perplexing because I see examples like: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252019/open-cv-object-detection-orb-gpu-detector-and-surf-gpu-descriptor-extractor) where the mask is defined like:

```
GpuMat mask(object_gpu.size(), CV_8U, 0xFF);
mask.setTo(0xFF);
```

When I try something like that, I do not even get past the compiler because it says that the mask call is unrecognized as a variant.

Any help on figuring out what is going on appreciated.

Comment: The mask Should be the same size as input Mat and with type **CV_8UC1 ** not CV_8U.